# If we take a vector out of a base and put a vector with all co-ordinates equal to $1$ on it's place it is not sure that we will get a base.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

A set of vectors: $ \alpha_1$, $ \alpha_2$, ...$ \alpha_n$ is a base of linear space $V$. Vector $\beta \in V$ has all co-ordinates equal to $1$. Is sequence $ \alpha_1$, $ \alpha_2$, ...$ \beta$ also a base of linear space V?

No, it is not. We can't be sure that after we took $\alpha_n$ out of the set of vectors $ \beta$ is not still dependent on any other of them. Particularly, among vectors $ \alpha_1$, $ \alpha_2$, ...$ \alpha_{n-1}$ there could be a vector that is equal to $ \beta$. Am I right?

Comment: You could compute the determinant of the matrix given by each of these vectors a columns and see it's nonzero to get that they are linearly independent and hence a basis. Or you could just directly show that it is impossible to write $\beta$ as a linear combination of the $\alpha_j$ for $j = 1,...,n-1$. Just do a proof by contradiction, start writing out equations, it's pretty straightforward

Comment: You are right!${}$

Comment: Your own answer is correct. $\beta$ could be any of the vectors $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_{n-1}$.

Comment: Your counterexample is very nice, but only works for $n>1$. This is because $n=1$ is indeed a case where you can replace any $\alpha_k$ by $\beta$ and are guaranteed to get a base again, i.e. your counterexample cannot work for $n=1$ because the statement is true for $n=1$. PS: I am not sure for $n=0$. Maybe somebody else can clarify this case?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you wrote is correct.

**It can even happens** that $\{\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dots, \alpha_{n-1}, \beta\}$ is not a basis while $\beta$ is not one of the $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dots, \alpha_{n-1}$.

For example take

$$\alpha_1 = \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}, \,
\alpha_2 = \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}, \,
\alpha_3 = \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\ 0\end{pmatrix}, \,
\beta = \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}
$$

$\beta \notin \{\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3\}$ but if you replace $\alpha_3$ by $\beta$, the new family of vectors is no more a basis.